# Как задать класс на 3 секунды, а потом удалить?

Tags: javascript

Как задать класс для блока на 3 секунды по клику на кнопку, а потом удалить его с помощью JS?

Comment: если считать что ничто не блочит основной поток то можно воспользоваться setTimeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

посмотрите в сторону [setTimeout](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval)

`setTimeout` позволяет вызвать функцию один раз через определённый интервал времени.

```
//функция которая удалит что-то по вашему желанию
function removeYourNeeds() {
  // do here your needs
}

// отложенный вызов функции removeYourNeeds
setTimeout(removeYourNeeds, 3000);
```